# How can I remove a word from a string if it occures more than 1 in a row with regex

Tags: java, regex

I want to remove the word `"<br>"` if it occures more than once consecutively. example

`"word word <br><br>"` becomes `"word word <br>"`

and `"word <br><br><br> word <br><br>"` becomes `"word <br> word<br>"`

I want to use replace or replace all if thats possible to keep it short

Comment: @user521180: question ain't exactly your question but... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348 You do really want to read the first answer :)

Comment: @Syntax but the first answer is a rediculously unreadable tirade on the evils of regular expressions who's link is posted on every question that has markup in it. I guess yours is one more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **I want to use replace or replace all if thats possible to keep it short**

Sure, it's possible:

```
yourString = yourString.replaceAll("(<br>)+", "<br>");
```

It basically means replace all *"`<br>` one or more times"* with just *"`<br>`"*.

Comment: Does it also capture the group?

Comment: @adarshr, what do you mean? If you're asking if the group can be used in the replacement string, the answer is yes, through `$1`.

Comment: @adarshr - yes, it captures a group for the replace. Poor cycles. If you're looking for efficiency you can write `(?:<br>){2,}`, but you may want to thing whether it's it's worth it.

Comment: Yes, that's precisely what I meant! :)

Answer (score 1):

This code is good to simplest situation:

```
str.replaceAll("(<br>)+", "<br>");
```

But if you want replace all br (case insensitive + ignore whitespaces), e.g.:

```
my word <BR>  <BR> blah blah -> my word <br> blah blah
```

I recommend you:

```
str.replaceAll("(?i)(<br>(\\s)*)+", "<br>")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a regex that matches the pattern only if it occurs more than one time.

Comment: aioobe took it one step further and gave you the answer.