# Coldfusion RegEx to replace characters

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I have the following code:

```
<cfset arguments.textToFormat = Replace(arguments.textToFormat, Chr(10), '<br />', "ALL") />
```

It replaces all instances of Chr(10) with a `<br />` tag.
What I'd like to do however is afterwards, if there are more than two `<br />` tags, replace all the extra ones with empty string (i.e. remove them)

I could do this via code, but I'm sure a regex replace would be faster. Unfortunately I haven't a clue how to construct the regex.

Any help would be great - thanks.

Comment: This was asked 16 minutes ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5184396/how-can-i-remove-a-word-from-a-string-if-it-occures-more-than-1-in-a-row-with-reg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There may be a more elegant regex, but this should do it:

```
rereplace( myText, '(<br />){2,}', '<br />', 'all' )
```

That should find all instances of 2 or more `<br />` tags, and replace the whole set with a single tag.